# NullpointerException at com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.configuration.Configuration.applyConfiguration only on Tomcat 8 (works fine on Tomcat 7)

Tags: java, datatables, tomcat8, dandelion, gvnix

I'm getting the following exception for Dandelion datatables when the application is deployed on Tomcat 8. The application works just fine on Tomcat 7. I've searched everywhere but can't find a resolution.

Snippet of the trace on Tomcat 8:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.configuration.Configuration.applyConfiguration(Configuration.java:283)
    at com.github.dandelion.datatables.jsp.tag.TableTag.doStartTag(TableTag.java:102)
    at org.gvnix.datatables.tags.RooTableTag.doStartTag(RooTableTag.java:133)
    at org.apache.jsp.tag.webdatatables.table_tagx.doTag(table_tagx.java:1346)
```

Dandelion in my web app is embedded in the "gvNix" dependencies.  The gvNix version is 1.4.0.RELEASE, which I assume includes the 0.10.1 version of Dandelion. The configuration being used is default. The application is packaged and deployed using Maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, gvNIX uses a Dandelion Datatables 0.9.2 custom-version which includes some patches  than hadn't been applied until 0.10.0 (it was due to release-time problems).

As far I know, we didn't make any test over Tomcat 8, so I think you found a bug ;-). If you want, you could report it on [github project](https://github.com/disid/gvnix/issues). Now a days, I can't provide you any workaround to run it on Tomcat 8.

I know that is planed to update Dandelion version but I can't provide you any schedule.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I created an issue in the GitHub but I also managed to workaround the problem. Please refer to https://github.com/gvSIGAssociation/gvnix/issues/28